# how to get the attribution from the JSON data

Tags: python, json

I'm learning Python Scrapy, and I'm scraping some online store website. When I analyse the product page, I want to get the color variation and the size variation. The data is in JSON format.

I use RE to get the "color" and "size":

```py
colors = re.findall('"propertyValueDisplayName":"(.*?)"',response.content.decode())
for color in colors:
    item["color"] = color
```

I get the color and size list, e.g. ["black","white","S","M","L"]

But I want the color and size separately, e.g. ["black","white"],
and then when I withdraw the size variation, ["S","M","L"].

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
           "id": 0,
            "name": "SKUModule",
            "productSKUPropertyList": [{
                "isShowTypeColor": true,
                "order": 1,
                "showType": "colour_atla",
                "showTypeColor": true,
                "skuPropertyId": 14,
                "skuPropertyName": "Color",
                "skuPropertyValues": [{
                    "propertyValueDefinitionName": "Black",
                    "propertyValueDisplayName": "Black",
                    "propertyValueId": 771,
                    "propertyValueIdLong": 771,
                    "propertyValueName": "Beige",
                    "skuColorValue": "#F8F7E7",
                    "skuPropertyImagePath": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ptOiX2vsK1Rjy0Fiq6zwtXXab/2018-Hot-Eroic-Underwear-Sex-Dress-Erotico-Sexy-Costumes-Lingerie-Rose-Pink-Backless-Halter-Women-Babydoll.jpg_640x640.jpg",
                    "skuPropertyImageSummPath": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ptOiX2vsK1Rjy0Fiq6zwtXXab/2018-Hot-Eroic-Underwear-Sex-Dress-Erotico-Sexy-Costumes-Lingerie-Rose-Pink-Backless-Halter-Women-Babydoll.jpg_50x50.jpg",
                    "skuPropertyTips": "Black",
                    "skuPropertyValueShowOrder": 1,
                    "skuPropertyValueTips": "Black"
                }, {
                    "propertyValueDefinitionName": "White",
                    "propertyValueDisplayName": "White",
                    "propertyValueId": 193,
                    "propertyValueIdLong": 193,
                    "propertyValueName": "Black",
                    "skuColorValue": "#000000",
                    "skuPropertyImagePath": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1sLGhX5YrK1Rjy0Fdq6ACvVXaJ/2018-Hot-Eroic-Underwear-Sex-Dress-Erotico-Sexy-Costumes-Lingerie-Rose-Pink-Backless-Halter-Women-Babydoll.jpg_640x640.jpg",
                    "skuPropertyImageSummPath": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1sLGhX5YrK1Rjy0Fdq6ACvVXaJ/2018-Hot-Eroic-Underwear-Sex-Dress-Erotico-Sexy-Costumes-Lingerie-Rose-Pink-Backless-Halter-Women-Babydoll.jpg_50x50.jpg",
                    "skuPropertyTips": "White",
                    "skuPropertyValueShowOrder": 1,
                    "skuPropertyValueTips": "White"
                }]
            }, {
                "isShowTypeColor": false,
                "order": 2,
                "showType": "none",
                "showTypeColor": false,
                "skuPropertyId": 5,
                "skuPropertyName": "Size",
                "skuPropertyValues": [{
                    "propertyValueDisplayName": "S",
                    "propertyValueId": 100014064,
                    "propertyValueIdLong": 100014064,
                    "propertyValueName": "S",
                    "skuPropertyTips": "S",
                    "skuPropertyValueShowOrder": 2,
                    "skuPropertyValueTips": "S"
                }, {
                    "propertyValueDisplayName": "M",
                    "propertyValueId": 361386,
                    "propertyValueIdLong": 361386,
                    "propertyValueName": "M",
                    "skuPropertyTips": "M",
                    "skuPropertyValueShowOrder": 2,
                    "skuPropertyValueTips": "M"
                }, {
                    "propertyValueDisplayName": "L",
                    "propertyValueId": 361385,
                    "propertyValueIdLong": 361385,
                    "propertyValueName": "L",
                    "skuPropertyTips": "L",
                    "skuPropertyValueShowOrder": 2,
                    "skuPropertyValueTips": "L"
                }]
            }],
            "skuPriceList": [{
                "skuAttr": "14:193#White;5:361385",
                "skuId": 66477180418,
                "skuPropIds": "193,361385",
                "skuVal": {
                    "actSkuCalPrice": "3.20",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.2",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.20",
                    "availQuantity": 624,
                    "inventory": 624,
                    "isActivity": true,
                    "optionalWarrantyPrice": [],
                    "skuActivityAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.20",
                        "value": 3.2
                    },
                    "skuAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.64",
                        "value": 3.64
                    },
                    "skuCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.64"
                }
            }, {
                "skuAttr": "14:193#White;5:100014064",
                "skuId": 66477180416,
                "skuPropIds": "193,100014064",
                "skuVal": {
                    "actSkuCalPrice": "3.20",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.2",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.20",
                    "availQuantity": 605,
                    "inventory": 605,
                    "isActivity": true,
                    "optionalWarrantyPrice": [],
                    "skuActivityAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.20",
                        "value": 3.2
                    },
                    "skuAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.64",
                        "value": 3.64
                    },
                    "skuCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.64"
                }
            }, {
                "skuAttr": "14:193#White;5:361386",
                "skuId": 66477180417,
                "skuPropIds": "193,361386",
                "skuVal": {
                    "actSkuCalPrice": "3.20",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.2",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.20",
                    "availQuantity": 619,
                    "inventory": 619,
                    "isActivity": true,
                    "optionalWarrantyPrice": [],
                    "skuActivityAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.20",
                        "value": 3.2
                    },
                    "skuAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.64",
                        "value": 3.64
                    },
                    "skuCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.64"
                }
            }, {
                "skuAttr": "14:771#Black;5:361386",
                "skuId": 66477180414,
                "skuPropIds": "771,361386",
                "skuVal": {
                    "actSkuCalPrice": "3.20",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.2",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.20",
                    "availQuantity": 600,
                    "inventory": 600,
                    "isActivity": true,
                    "optionalWarrantyPrice": [],
                    "skuActivityAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.20",
                        "value": 3.2
                    },
                    "skuAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.64",
                        "value": 3.64
                    },
                    "skuCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.64"
                }
            }, {
                "skuAttr": "14:771#Black;5:361385",
                "skuId": 66477180415,
                "skuPropIds": "771,361385",
                "skuVal": {
                    "actSkuCalPrice": "3.20",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.2",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.20",
                    "availQuantity": 608,
                    "inventory": 608,
                    "isActivity": true,
                    "optionalWarrantyPrice": [],
                    "skuActivityAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.20",
                        "value": 3.2
                    },
                    "skuAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.64",
                        "value": 3.64
                    },
                    "skuCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.64"
                }
            }, {
                "skuAttr": "14:771#Black;5:100014064",
                "skuId": 66477180413,
                "skuPropIds": "771,100014064",
                "skuVal": {
                    "actSkuCalPrice": "3.20",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.2",
                    "actSkuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.20",
                    "availQuantity": 599,
                    "inventory": 599,
                    "isActivity": true,
                    "optionalWarrantyPrice": [],
                    "skuActivityAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.20",
                        "value": 3.2
                    },
                    "skuAmount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "formatedAmount": "US $3.64",
                        "value": 3.64
                    },
                    "skuCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice": "3.64",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice": "3.64"
                }
            }],
            "warrantyDetailJson": "[]"
        },
```

How do I get the color and size data separately?

Comment: You don't need regex to search through json, just put it in a dictionary and loop through `productSKUPropertyList`

Comment: thank you @CMMCD, and it is not work,because i want the black and S is not in same list.

Comment: You can loop through multiple lists one after another or use the zip command to loop through multiple at once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the json provided is correct JSON response from the request.  the below code could work

```
productSKUPropertyList = response.json()['productSKUPropertyList']
for sku in productSKUPropertyList:
    colors.append(sku['skuPropertyValues']['propertyValueDisplayName']) 
print colors
```

Please try this once. Or make necessary modifications

Comment: hi,Jithin P James,thank you for your fast reply and i get some idea from your offer and understand it. but when loop it, the color :black and size:S is in the same list. because there are same "Key" :``"propertyValueDefinitionName": "Black","propertyValueDisplayName": "S",` we want get it in different list. not use for slice,because i can make sure the postion when the colors is 2 or 3 or 4

Comment: there is the only different place:  "skuPropertyName": "Color","skuPropertyName": "Size", how to get the position and use the RE ,it is the point

Comment: please check it again,tks

Comment: Can you give me the api to which you are making the request? This will help me to work on the actual response.